# How can I make heading and sub heading using multilistbox in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make heading and sub heading using multilistbox in tkinter. I am able to make sub heading. Heare is my code.

```
from tkinter import *

from modules.listview import MultiListbox

root = Tk()

mlb = MultiListbox(root, (('Student One', 25), ('Student Two', 25), ('Student Three', 25)))

mlb.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

---

```
       Students Name
```

---

Students1    Students2    Students3

---

In my first heading I needed students name
and second in my sud heading I needed student1, student2, student3.

I need this picture:

[image: I needed this picture]

I am able to make this:

[image: I am able to make this]

Comment: If all you need is a header - why don't you just put a `Label` on top of your listbox?

Comment: I'm thinking, I do this using Multilistbox. But I don't know is it possible or not using Multilistbox. If I have no way then I will use Label.